# how to run an application from a different user than the user that installed the application

Tags: users, .desktop, multiple-users

I have 2 user accounts, user_1 and user_2. I installed intellij under user_1 before creating the user_2 account. After I created user_2 and logged in as user_2, I cannot see the intellij application when I do a search like I would if I log into user_1. I've searched this site for answers. So far I have found none.

I would imagine that this is a fairly common thing. How can I make user_2 see an application installed under user_1 and further run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that your .desktop file for intellij only installed in the original users ~/.local/share/applications/intellij.desktop is what creates an icon you can search for and launch. If intellij wasn't actually Installed to that user locally try the following.

```
cp /home/user2/.local/share/applications/intellij.desktop /home/user1/.local/share/applications/intellij.desktop
sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

You could also add the .desktop file for All users

```
 cp /home/user2/.local/share/applications/intellij.desktop /usr/share/applications/intellij.desktop
```

Please note that the .desktop file may not be called intellij.desktop, but you should be able to find it.

Edit: It's possible that intellij was installed locally to user_2. If that is the case then copying the .desktop file won't work. The .desktop file essentially tells Ubuntu what to do when a user wants to launch that application. If a user doesn't have permissions to the files it won't work.

Comment: I looked at my directories and found that intellij was put under the `/home/user_1/Downloads/` directory. The .desktop file was named `jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`, which was in `/home/user_1/.local/share/applications/` directory. After reading your answer, I decided to move the software from `Downloads` directory to `/opt` directory. Then when I run it for the first time, I run "configure/Create Desktop Entry" in the start window. Now both of my user accounts can see it.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you most likely didn't install the program using apt-get.
your main solutions, are either to install intellij in user_2, or you could find the executable. if you installed using .tar.gz, then it might be in your home directory. so, on user_2 you open a terminal, and type `cd /home/user_1/.name_of_intellij_directory` of course, replacing user_1 with the name of user_1, and replacing .name_of_intellij_directory with the name of the intellij directory. if you don't know then name, you will have to open nautilus go to root>home>user_1 and press ctrl+h yo show hidden folders. you should see the name of the intellj directory there. then you go back to the terminal and type `ls -la` (assuming you already used the cd command) and post the output in your original post.